# SOAP web service authentication

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, authentication, soap

I am adding my very first SOAP web service to a large existing Web Forms application.

I think I've worked out the technical details to make this work. However, I still have questions about authentication. One option is to simply have my web method take a username/password parameter, something like the following:

```
[WebService(Namespace = PublicServices.XmlnsNamespace)]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class PublicServices : WebService
{
    public const string XmlnsNamespace = "http://xmlns.domain.com/publicapi";

    [WebMethod]
    public ProgramData GetProgramData(string userName, string password, string programCode)
    {
        // Gather and return program data here
    }
}
```

My question is what are the downsides of this approach. Web Forms has its own authentication code, and I see WCF has tools for authentication as well. I also saw something about "custom authentication using SOAP headers", which I know nothing about.

Is there a more secure approach than this? Any suggestions to get me on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one endpoint/interface which exposes Login/Logout methods. Login exposes login and password parameters and authenticates user. It returns some key which uniquely identifies user such as hash of login & password. Subsequently, you create another endpoint such as PublicServices. Every single request sent towards service contains obtained hash placed in header. Once the service receives message it validates hash against some resource such as database. If it is incorrect error is thrown and no method is ever reached. As far as WCF is concerned, you need to specify custom classes which derive *IClientMessageInspector* and *IDispatchMessageInspector* for client and service respectively. 
What is benefit of such a solution? Distinct separation between what service does and request's validation. Sloppy solution is to sent hash as method's parameter and validate it within every single method exposed by service.